# Spring web application property override problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring web application with an applicationContext.xml file in the WEB-INF directory. In that file I have the following definitions:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/etc/mycompany/myapp.properties"
                              order="-1" ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myapp-defaults.properties"
                              order="0" ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Then I have a class, com.mycompany.MyClass:

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Service("myClassService")
public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    @Value("${myprop}")
    private String myProp;
}
```

I have two properties files, myapp.properties (located in the classpath) and /etc/mycompany/myapp.properties. Both of these define the myprop property with different values.

If I comment out both of the  elements in my applicationContext.xml file and print out the value of the myProp variable, I get the value "${myprop}" (this is expected).

However, now for the weird part. If I just comment out one of the lines I **always** get the value from the classpath properties file. Note that it doesn't matter which property-placeholder line I comment out. Even if I comment out the one including the classpath properties definition, I still get the classpath properties value into the variable.

If I use a property that is only defined in the filesystem properties file I get the correct value.

So in other words, there seems to be no way for me to override the values in myapp-defaults.properties (in the classpath) by defining them in the properties file on my filesystem. The only way to get properties from a file on the filesystem is if that property is not defined in the classpath properties file.

I have tried reversing the order attribute to no avail (as I understand, this is the correct way, the lower number should have precedence).

I also tried debugging my application and put a breakpoint at select places in the Spring source code. I was able to see that the properties were being loaded from the filesystem properties file. When I commented out the classpath property-placeholder I noted that the filesystem property file was being loaded correctly but when the variable value was printed out it still had the value defined in the classpath properties file.

I'm really confused here. Is there some pitfall I'm falling into here?

Comment: You have probably issues with project cleanup. It is not possible to get properties from file which is commented out... in Eclipse try to use `Project > Clean`. Or there is some other aspect which you didn't mention.

Comment: Unfortunately I've eliminated that as being the issue. I've cleaned everything up and deleted all generated files in between builds.

I'm sure there is some other aspect that I haven't mentioned. The problem is finding what aspect that is and fixing it.

Comment: Ugh... figured it out... well, sortof. At least I know what to do to avoid this problem manifesting itself. Will be adding an answer shortly.

Comment: Nevermind... that wasn't it. But I'm getting closer to the source of the problem. It seems to have something to do with the project using the org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext. Not quite sure what the solution is (or if there really is one) but I'll report back when I have a clearer picture of what's actually going on.